# curl (58) unable to load client cert -8912

Tags: linux, azure, curl

I'm having trouble communicating with Azure using curl from linux. When I send the followig command:

curl -E "/home/rainey/azure-cert.cer" -H "x-ms-version: 2014-05-09" "[https://management.core.windows.net/[subscription](https://management.core.windows.net/%5bsubscription) id]/services/hostedservices"

- I get the following error:
  curl (58) unable to load client cert -8912

What am I missing?

Comment: Two things: 1. did you upload the cert to the management cert store in your subscription via the portal or PowerShell?  2. give the details of how you created your cert.

Comment: Hi sebastus, I uploaded the cert using the azure portal. It was created as follows:  openssl x509 -outform der -in azure-cert.pem azure-cert.cer

Comment: The pem file was created using: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout azure-cert.pem -out azure-cert.pem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .pem file in the cURL command line.  The .cer is used to upload to the Management Cert store in the Azure portal.

Here are a couple blog posts with lots of working examples:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2012/11/29/how-to-use-the-windows-azure-service-management-api-from-curl-to-create-virtual-machines.aspx

http://blog.toddysm.com/2012/01/accessing-windows-azure-rest-apis-with-curl.html